# Encountering errors within Spring Security despite not utilizing WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm working with Spring Boot version 3.1.9 and I've encountered that WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is marked as deprecated in this version.

```
package net.engineeringdigest.journalApp.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurity {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/journal/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();

        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
}
```

The code snippet provided is encountering the following deprecation warnings and errors:

1. 'csrf()' is deprecated since version 6.1 and marked for removal
2. 'authorizeHttpRequests()' is deprecated since version 6.1 and marked for removal
3. 'and()' is deprecated since version 6.1 and marked for removal
4. 'httpBasic()' is deprecated since version 6.1 and marked for removal